# What is the license for the data shared on Jounral of Political Economics

Tags: publications, data, economics

I don't think Journal of Political Economics has suggested a specific license. However, the journal did say that the data policy is adopted from American Economic Review (AER). AER did suggest a license of Creative Commons Attribution International 4.0 (CC-BY).

That license allows reuse of data without asking permission (I just have to cite it). So my question is, may I also use the data released by JPE without asking permission?

Comment: At least in US law, data by itself is not protected by copyright, so a license would be legally meaningless, unless it is the compilation of the data over which copyright is being asserted, which may or may not be a possibility depending on the nature of the dataset. See [here](https://libguides.library.kent.edu/data-management/copyright) and  [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/63139/public-dataset-without-license-what-is-allowed) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

A "suggested" license isn't necessarily imposed on authors. Especially one that is second hand. Ask the authors if you can't otherwise get a definitive answer.

Some journals might *impose* a license, but you should be sure, rather than make assumptions.